# How do I make it clear to Google that my domain name contains `www` like www.wwwexample.com?

Tags: seo, domains, google-search, search-engine-indexing

I've noticed that domain names containing `www` (e.g., `http://www.wwwexample.com`) sometimes are ranked lower in search results.

I have also noticed that Google assumes it to be `www.example.com`. For example, 
my domain name has the format of `www.wwwexample.com`, and when I search on it,  the first results are not my domain, but the one with `www` omitted (i.e., `www.example.com`). Both of these domains however refer to totally different content.

Is there any strategy or approach to making it clear to Google that it's actually `www.wwwexample.com` and not `www.example.com`?

Comment: It sounds it is auto-correcting the wwwsomename since it assumes you forgot a period. This is to be expected since www.wwwsomename looks spammy and/or wrong. Also check your routing and verifies to make sure both variants are set correctly....but im guessing its auto-correcting somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `www` in a domain name like `www.wwwexample.com` is likely confusing to users and Google as well, since `www` is usually a subdomain.

If you're not open to reconsidering the domain name, then the following strategy should be helpful:

1. You should probably `301` redirect `www.wwwexample.com` to the root domain `wwwexample.com` to make the URL and links a bit clearer to users.
2. Setup a Google Webmasters Tools account `wwwexample.com` and [verify](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179?hl=en) it.
3. Tell Google that the [preferred domain](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en) is `wwwexample.com`
4. [Submit a sitemap](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/100283?hl=en) containing links to just `wwwexample.com`
5. Make sure your titles and content state  `wwwexample.com` (without any space after the `www`)
6. Try to obtain as many (quality) [backlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backlink) from other sites to help Google build trust and recognition for `wwwexample.com`

Comment: will try one by one and will see what are changes. Thanks for ideas.

Other ideas are welcome as well.

Comment: No problem. Ultimately, you can't really control what Google does, but the above might help. Good luck.